# Displaying Button Above Image in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, imageview

I am making an android application in which i have an `ImageView` and an `Forward Arrow Button` ,All i want is to display the button at the Right Center of the screen above the image.
Here is my code.....

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageShow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

 <EditText
android:id="@+id/postal_address"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@string/postal_address_hint"
android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
```

Comment: use `RelativeLayout` and put whatever you want and wherever.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageShow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/YOUR_BUTTON_ID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/ImageShow" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```